# Interrupting a job in quartz with multiple instances

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have 5 instances of an application using quartz in cluster mode both having the quartz scheduler running. (with postgresql)

```
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered:true
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: myInstanceName
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
```

So I have a job which starts and do some operations, update itself if necessary with new scheduled time or else deletes itself. (One job can contain only one trigger.)

The application has a UI interface to allow the user to cancel the job.

When the interrupt command is send from the UI;

If job is not currently working; I can pause the job or cancel.

If my job is currently working at that time, how can I stop the job with the correct instance and get the current state of the job? Basically I want to catch at that moment and save that data at that time, which user is actually interrupt moment

Does scheduler.interrupt(jobKey) interrupt my job which implements InterruptableJob correctly ?

Is scheduler.interrupt() exactly knows which instance should currently running the job and find the correct instance and get the right state of the job ?

Can u correct me, or which way should I go with ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

interrupt method implementations and getCurrentlyExecutingJobs() in quartz are not cluster aware,

which means the method has to be run on the instance which is executing that job, in other words only jobs with specified job key running in the current instance will be interrupted.

An interrupt request can be broadcasted to all running instances of quartz to cancel all instances of running jobs.

from: https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#interrupt(org.quartz.JobKey)

> This method is not cluster aware. That is, it will only interrupt
> instances of the identified InterruptableJob currently executing in
> this Scheduler instance, not across the entire cluster.

Comment: Re:  "An interrupt request can be broadcasted to all running instances of quartz to cancel all instances of running jobs."

Do you mean sending the interrupt request to all running instances of the _Application_ running Quartz?  What if that's not an option?  For example, the source of the interrupt request cannot address each Application instance directly.